# Efficiently indexing matrix and making package CoopGame less memory intensive

Tags: r, indexing, sparse-matrix

In brief: I am running out of memory when indexing a very large matrix. I am trying to solve the problem by using a sparse matrix and using a more efficient indexing approach.

More specifically:
I am using a function from the R package CoopGame::createBitMatrix. This function returns a matrix with n+1 columns and 2^(n - 1) rows. The elements contained in the matrix are either 0 or 1 (see for more details below[1]).

The only argument required by createBitMatrix is n, which is very high in my case (n = 27), and as a result R runs out of memory.

Here is how createBitMatrix works (I am copy-pasting from the code of the function). Observe that I am reducing n to 10 in order to make it faster to replicate the code.

```
n = 10
N = 2^n - 1
bm <- matrix(rep(0, N * n), nrow = N, ncol = n, byrow = TRUE)
rownum <- 1
for (i in 1:n) {
    combo <- utils::combn(n, i)
    for (j in 1:ncol(combo)) {
        for (k in 1:nrow(combo)) {
            bm[rownum, combo[k, j]] <- 1
        }
        rownum <- rownum + 1
    }
}
```

In the attempt to make this operation more efficient, I wrote the following code to replicate the output returned by createBitMatrix using less memory.

In this code, I leverage the fact that a matrix can be indexed as a vector to reduce the number of required loops. Also, I make use of a sparse matrix.

```
library(Matrix)
bm2 <- sparseMatrix(i={}, j={}, dims=list(N, n))
rownum <- 1
ind_i <- c()
for (i in 1:n) {
    combo <- utils::combn(n, i)
    ind_j <- c()
    for (j in 1:ncol(combo)) {
        y <- combo[, j]
        ind <- rownum + nrow(bm) * (y - 1)
        ind_j <- c(ind_j, ind)
        rownum <- rownum + 1
    }
    ind_i <- c(ind_i, ind_j)
    print(n - i)
}
bm2[ind_i] <- TRUE
```

The two matrices are identical (i.e. TRUE and FALSE values are positioned exactly in the same way both in bm and bm2). However my code is very slow and when I set n back to 27 I am not even able to tell if R will eventually run out of memory (I had to stop the code after some time).

I am struggling to understand whether it is possible to further reduce the number of loops and reduce computation time.

Any advise would be very much appreciated.

[1] From the help page: createBitMatrix creates a bit matrix with (numberOfPlayers+1) columns and (2^numberOfPlayers-1) rows which contains all possible coalitions (apart from the null coalition) for the set of all players.

Comment: What on earth could you possibly be doing with this data structure that you need to store it instead of generating it on the fly as needed.

Comment: @CJR I don't understand what you are suggesting. CoopGame::createBitMatrix creates a matrix that is later used to run some analysis in the context of game theory. Do you think there is a better way to do this?

Comment: It seems to me you have an XY problem. You want help storing a giant matrix which is very, very easy to generate. You should be just generating this in conjunction with your analysis and not storing the stupid thing at all. From a time-memory standpoint what you are doing is trading a massive amount of memory for very, very little time.

Comment: @CJR maybe I am missing something here. CoopGame::createBitMatrix is not able to generate a matrix with the dimension I need. I am trying to find a solution to that. Observe that I do not need help to store a giant matrix (that I have already done it using the sparse matrix). I need to efficiently insert values inside the matrix using the rule of CoopGame::createBitMatrix. Once I have obtained the matrix, I can use it for my analysis. I am sorry but I really don't understand what is your point.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Your code will never work because unlike setting a value in an allocated matrix which is fast, building a vector with iterative c() is very slow and inefficient. Also changing the sparsity of a csr matrix is very slow so don't do that iteratively either.

Comment: c() is not efficient, I agree with you. Still, I need to loop in order to know what entries have to be filled in the matrix. However, I think I have found a workaround and I am close to a solution. It is not very efficient, still I can get what I need in a reasonable time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some trial and error I found this solution by using sparse matrices and parallel processing. It allows to work with n very large in a relatively fast way. The result is equal to that provided by CoopGame::createBitMatrix.

```
createBitMatrix_parallel(n, cl = 2) {

require(parallel)
require(doParallel)
require(progressr)
require(foreach)
require(Matrix)
require(purrr)

cl <- makeCluster(cl)
doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
iterations <- n
progressr::with_progress({
    p <- progressr::progressor(along = iterations)
   
    bm <- foreach(i = 1:iterations, .packages = c("Matrix")) %dopar%
        {
            combo <- combn(n, i)
            ncol_combo <- ncol(combo)
            nrow_combo <- nrow(combo)
            is <- rep(1:ncol_combo, each = nrow_combo)
            res <- sparseMatrix(i={is}, j={combo}, dims=list(ncol_combo, n))
            return(res)
        }
})

bm <- do.call("rbind", bm)
return(bm) 

}
```

Comment: The answer is correct. It would be useful to receive a feedback by who downvoted it to understand if there is any problem with the script.